# C# Test proxy settings as in Windows Service

Tags: c#, proxy, windows-services

I'm making an app that will run as a Windows Service. It needs to connect to a web service, so it also has a form where the user can set up their proxy. This form has a button to test the proxy settings. When this form is running, the app runs within a user's session context (unlike than with the Windows Service).

So, the user sets up a proxy without its credentials and when tested it works great because of active session credentials. But when the Windows Service tries to use the proxy setup with different credentials (I guess Local System or Network Service), it fails.

How can I test the proxy settings as if running under a Windows Service?

Comment: When you say "no credentials", I don't think you really mean that. The windows service is running under an account of some sort; it may be Local System or Network Service, but it is still an account from the OS perspective.

Comment: Have you tried this: http://geek.hubkey.com/2008/02/impersonating-built-in-service-account.html

Comment: I've just tried, it works but then the app would need to be run by a high privileges user.